# What will be potential energy at a point when we bring a charge from infinity with acceleration?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy

So electric potential energy of a charge at a point in an electric field is defined as the amount of work done in bringing a charge from infinity to that point with a constant velocity.

But what would happen if we provide some extra external force in bringing that charge from infinity to that point. Will the charge have some extra potential energy since we have done extra work in bringing that charge.

Answer (score 2):

No, the potential energy only depends on the position of the charge. The additional work being done will increase the kinetic energy of the charge.